# CMD: error " No se encuentra el archivo E:/ *.* " ¿Virus?

Tags: windows, cmd, usb

Necesito saber como es el comando para desbloquear un pendrive por **CMD**. He averiguado aparte por internet y los códigos que he probado, todos me han arrojado este error:

> No se encuentra el archivo `E:/`.

Y los códigos que he probado son:

1. `attrib -s -h -r /s /d`
2. `attrib /s /d -r -h -s *.*`

Si tienen alguna solución por favor ayúdenme. Necesito recuperar el **pendrive**, no los datos.

Comment: Pues me falto explicar esto, es que el pendrive es de 4gb, me aparece que tiene disponible 2,5gb, y usado 1,54gb, pero cuando abro el pendrive no aparece nada absolutamente nada, además para pasar archivos a ese pendrive se tarda demasiado , cosa que no me sucede con otros pendrives, solo con este, puede ser daño tanto fisico como interno...

Comment: Si exactamente.

Comment: Está en FAT32, añado que cuando hice click derecho dentro de la unidad y le di a propiedades, apareció en la unidad un archivo temporal que por lo que log´re ver se llamaba readyboost... .tmp, - verificaré lo de `dir /a e: -

Comment: El volumen de la unidad es E:

Comment: La resolución de tu problema puede llevar tiempo y necesito más preguntas, [continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90030/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-abdiel).

Comment: El numero de serie del volumen es : 3299-8837

Answer (score 1):

Deberias intentar primero hacer un `chkdsk /r` o `chkdsk /f` al pendrive y después utilizar los comandos que describes para desbloquear cada uno de los ficheros. Debes tener en cuenta que el pendrive tenga el mismo tamaño que dice tener, o sea que no se trate de una falsificación. Me he topado con pendrive que dicen tener 8GB cuando en realidad el chip de almacenamiento es de 4. Que al copiar más información de la que en realidad puede almacenar termina corrompiendo los datos. Y por supuesto la última opción puede ser el formatear el pendrive.

Comment: Hola amigo, pues lo que dices ya lo he hecho , y me sale un largo proceso que recuerdo que decía repetidamente como que "se repararon los archivos" y "archivo huerfano no se pudo corregir" y al final que me dice desea almacenar estos archivos ocultos en una unidad? s/n , pues coloco "s" para si y me dice que no hay espacio suficiente para realizarlo, y como que no hace nada practicamente.

Comment: Entonces vas a tener que formatear el pendrive. Dale un formateo rapido y luego intenta con un Get DataBack, Recuva u otro programa de recuperacion de datos. Porque ciertamente no puedes acceder a la informacion real del pendrive e intentar eliminar algo para que chkdsk tenga espacio para trabajar.